# How to select one feature continously with Select Control?

Tags: openlayers

openlayers:6.1.1

I want to select feature.Here is code:

```
const select = new Select({
        toggleCondition:singleClick,
        // removeCondition: singleClick,
        style:false,
    })
map.addInteraction(select)
select .on('select', callBack)
function callBack(result) {
        console.log('select',result)
      
    },
```

When I first click feature,console.log worked.Then I click feature second,there is nothing happenning.
How to always dispatch select event?
Thank you~

Comment: It should be working (it does here https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-kapitsa-h0itv?file=/main.js)  You cannot select a feature which is already selected but with your toggleCondition every click on a feature should fire an event.

Comment: thanks,I see it.map.on('click') solve everything~